# Integrate $\int_{a}^{b}\left [\int_{a}^{x} (t-a)(t-b)\left(t-\frac{a+b}{2} \right) dt \right]dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods

The following integral arrives me, while reading *Atkinson*'s book on *Numerical Analysis*. It's pretty simple but I'm not sure what theorems should I be using:

I have to integrate the following:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \left [\int_{a}^{x} (t-a)(t-b)\left (t-\frac{a+b}{2} \right ) dt \right ]dx $$

what my professor does is the following:

$\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b} \left [\int_{a}^{x} (t-a)(t-b)\left(t-\frac{a+b}{2}\right) dt \right ]dx & =
\int_{a}^{b} \left [\int_{a}^{b} (t-a)(t-b)\left(t-\frac{a+b}{2} \right) dx \right ]dt \\
& = \int_{a}^{b}(t-a)(t-b)\left (t-\frac{a+b}{2} \right )(b-t) dt
\end{align}
$

I'd say he's using Fubini's theorem in the first equality, but the rest doesn't make much sense to me.

**Edit:**

Reading further in the book *Atkinson* states:

> For any integrable function $G(x,t)$:
>   $$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{x}G(x,t)dt \cdot dx = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{t}^{b}G(x,t)dx \cdot dt$$

so why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are integrating the function $(t-a)(t-b)\left(t-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$ over the triangular domain $a\leq t\leq x\leq b$, so by switching the order of integration we get
$$ I(a,b)=\int_{a}^{b}(t-a)(t-b)\left(t-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)(b-t)\,dt $$
since for a given $t\in[a,b]$, the measure of the set $\{x\in[a,b]:t\leq x\leq b\}$ is exactly $(b-t)$.
With the change of variable $t=a+b-u$ we get:
$$ I(a,b) = \int_{a}^{b}(b-u)(a-u)\left(\frac{a+b}{2}-u\right)(u-a)\,du $$
hence:
$$ I(a,b) = \int_{a}^{b}(a+b-2t)^2(t-a)(b-t)\,dt = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{b-a}{2}}(b-a-2t)^2 t(b-a-t)\,dt$$
and:
$$ I(a,b) = 2(b-a)^5 \int_{0}^{1/2}(1-2t)^2 t(1-t)\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{(b-a)^5}{30}}.$$